# Minimum height for desktop - media query

Tags: css, media-queries

I want to target horizontal mode tablet - but not desktop. What is the correct media query setting for that?

Answer (score 1):

The usual width of tablet devices ranges from `768px to 1200px`.

The minimum width of desktop devices is `1200px`.

This table shows most common breakpoints for each type of device:
[image]

Comment: thanks but what about the height?